# How to get the color of a given pixel in world coordinates?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, godot

I'm using Godot's fragment shader. I can get the world coordinates of the current pixel like this:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
```

Lets say I increase pixel_world_pos.y by 10 and I want to know what color that pixel is. How can I figure that out?

I know that information is stored in the UV, but I'm in world coordinates, not UV coordinates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us have a closer look at this line:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
```

Here, you take `VERTEX` which would be in view space. Augment it to a `vec4` with `1.0` on the `w` coordinate. And then transform it with `CAMERA_MATRIX`.

The `CAMERA_MATRIX` takes the `vec4` from view space to world space (i.e. `CAMERA_MATRIX` is an inverse view matrix). And then you take a `vec3` from it, discarding `w`.

---

Alright, let us say next you modify the `y` coordinate like this:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
```

And you want to know where that is in view space. Well… We do what we did, but in reverse.

Last thing we did was discarding `w`. We need to add `w` back:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
vec4 tmp = vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
```

*This works under the assumption that `CAMERA_MATRIX` is a 3D affine transformation.*

The prior thing you did was transforming the vector with `CAMERA_MATRIX`. To undo that we need to transform the vector with the inverse of `CAMERA_MATRIX` (a.k.a. the view matrix). Godot provides that as `INV_CAMERA_MATRIX`. So we transform with that:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
vec4 tmp = INV_CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
```

And the first thing you did was augmenting the vector. So let us discard `w` now:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
vec3 pixel_view_pos = (INV_CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0)).xyz;
```

And there you go.

---

Oh, wait you want to read the pixel. So we need UV. The next step is to use the `PROJECTION_MATRIX`.

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
```

Here I'm composing the view matrix (`INV_CAMERA_MATRIX`) with the projection matrix (`PROJECTION_MATRIX`) so we can convert directly from world space to clip space. That is `INV_CAMERA_MATRIX` takes us from world space to view space, and the `PROJECTION_MATRIX` takes us from view space to clip space.

Before we go further, we need to deal with the fact that the `PROJECTION_MATRIX` hold a projection transformation (surprise!), which is not an affine transformation. So we should not be adding and removing `w`, instead, we do do this:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
vec4 pixel_clip_pos = WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
vec3 pixel_nds_pos = pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w;
```

Here `dns` stands for normalized device space. We can discard `z` now:

```
vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
vec4 pixel_clip_pos = WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
vec2 uv = (pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w).xy * 0.5 + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
```

However, as it turns out, if we simply do `(pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w).xy`, we get coordinates with the origin in the center of the screen. So we need to scale and offset them so they go from zero at the bottom left corner to one at the top right corner. Which is how screen uv works.

*By the way, the `z` we discarded would be useful if you wanted to compute depth.*

---

And we are done:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment()
{
    vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
    pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
    mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
    vec4 pixel_clip_pos = WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
    vec2 uv = (pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w).xy * 0.5 + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    ALBEDO = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, uv).rgb;
}
```

By the way, you need to be aware that the `uv` you compute might go beyond the edge of `SCREEN_TEXTURE`.