# How to determine the presence of a mesh in world coordinates?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, godot, vertex-shader

I'm using Godot's fragment shader.

```
vec3 pixel_world_position = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
```

I'd like to know if there is a mesh or something to be drawn at pixel_world_position.
In other-words, is there empty space at this point or is there a solid material.

How can I figure that out?

Comment: You can only read what you get as textures or uniforms. There is a `DEPTH_TEXTURE` that you should be able to get. And if you compute depth and compare with that you could tell if there is something between the camera and the point you have. I tried to get it to work to write an answer, but could not.

Comment: @Theraot Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on how one might figure out if there was something between the camera and the pixel given the DEPTH_TEXTURE. I'd like to try to research it a bit more, but it seems to me that depth would just tell me the depth of the pixel relative to the camera, but I'm not sure how I could tell if a material were in between it?

Comment: If you can compute where on the screen and at what depth a position would be, then you can read the depth on that same position of the screen and compare. Everything going well, you would be able to tell if the position is in front or behind whatever is being shown on screen, similar to how depth test works. Something similar is done for shadow mapping (if there is something closer to the light than can be seen from the light, it is in shadow) looking into that might help understand the idea. Also have a look at the documentation of `DEPTH_TEXTURE`.

Answer (score 0):

*This took much more figuring out than expected.*

---

Let us begin with the code from the [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759991/402022):

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment()
{
    vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
    pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
    mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
    vec4 pixel_clip_pos = WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
    vec2 uv = (pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w).xy * 0.5 + vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    ALBEDO = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, uv).rgb;
}
```

The first change is that we are not going to discard `z` right away. Instead, let us do this:

```
    vec3 screen_pos = (pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w) * 0.5 + vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    vec2 uv = screen_pos.xy;
```

This way we can read the `z` we calculated and compare it with the depth buffer.

Speaking of the depth buffer, we are going to read it with that `uv`:

```
    float depth = textureLod(DEPTH_TEXTURE, uv, 0.0).r;
```

And this is how we are going to check:

```
    float check = step(depth - screen_pos.z, 0.0001);
```

So we will have `0.0` if `0.0001` is smaller than the difference, and `1.0` otherwise. That is, if `screen_pos.z` is closer to the camera than `depth` (with a bias of `0.0001`), you get `0.0`, otherwise `1.0`. In other words, you get `1.0` if `depth` is less or equal to `screen_pos.z` (with a bias of `0.0001`). That is, you get `1.0` if there is something at `screen_pos.z` (with a bias of `0.0001`) or closer to the camera.

And finally, we use that when setting the `ALBEDO`:

```
ALBEDO = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, uv).rgb * check + vec3(0.0) * (1.0 - check);
```

In this case, if the depth says there is something, it will have the color form the screen texture. Otherwise black (`vec3(0.0)`).

---

Full code listing:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment()
{
    vec3 pixel_world_pos = (CAMERA_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX, 1.0)).xyz;
    pixel_world_pos.y = pixel_world_pos.y + 10.0;
    mat4 WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX = PROJECTION_MATRIX * INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;
    vec4 pixel_clip_pos = WORLD_TO_CLIP_MATRIX * vec4(pixel_world_pos, 1.0);
    vec3 screen_pos = (pixel_clip_pos.xyz / pixel_clip_pos.w) * 0.5 + vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    vec2 uv = screen_pos.xy;
    float depth = textureLod(DEPTH_TEXTURE, uv, 0.0).r;
    float check = step(depth - screen_pos.z, 0.0001);
    ALBEDO = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, uv).rgb * check + vec3(0.0) * (1.0 - check);
}
```

I want to put emphasis on the fact this will output from the `SCREEN_TEXTURE` if it found something at that depth *or closer to the camera*. There is no way for this code to query geometry that is not visible.

Also, in theory it should be `0.0` not `0.0001`, but with `0.0` you would have artifacts analog to shadow acne. So `0.0001` is a bias to fix that, much like you would use a bias to fix shadow acne in shadow mapping.